# Auto update a closed testing app on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I have an issue where the app is not auto updating. This is happening for both the Internal and Closed testing tracks.

The app is installed from Google Play store. When I navigate to App Info -> App details, it navigates to the Play Store listing and the "Update" button is there. "Enable auto-update" checkbox is checked. However it just won't update by itself.

One more thing I have noticed is that the app does not appear in the list of apps (Play Store -> Manage apps and device -> Manage -> Installed). It's just not there in any of the tabs, I guess this is the reason it's not getting an update either.

Comment: That's normal. You will need to tell your testers that an update is available. I don't know how google determines when to auto-update, but for example one app on my phone had an update for a few days now and didn't auto update.

Comment: Oh and if it's not in the installed list, look again, because when it's installed *via the PlayStore*, and not in that list... well let's call that "impossible" for now :D

Comment: @Elias I agree that's totally weird. I can reproduce this only on my personal Pixel 5 so far. Since my post I have left the closed testing programme and installed the production version from the Play Store to try that out. It's still not in the Play Store list of installed apps. Furthermore now the App details link to the Play Store listing isn't working, I'm getting a "Try Again" screen instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, sometimes it will take days before it got automatically updated!

I Use [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/products/app-distribution) it is still in BETA but it is reliable. it is very quick to push new updates for all your testers.

Comment: I use Firebase App Distribution too and it's amazing for internal testing. However my use case is a group of external users that have agreed to closed testing the new versions.

So far I'm finding Google Play Store quite disappointing, stuff just isn't working as stated in documentation.